# EGLImageTargetTexture2DOES target parameter, when to use TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES vs TEXTURE_2D

Tags: opengl-es, egl

If I understand correctly from reading the [OES_EGL_image_external spec](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/OES/OES_EGL_image_external.txt), for the `EGLImageTargetTexture2DOES` function one can either use the `TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` target, and then you'll need to sample the EGL image via `samplerExternalOES` sampler in the shader, or, if the GL_OES_EGL_image extension is supported by the GL context, one can also simply use regular 2D texture samplers with the `TEXTURE_2D` target.

Assuming I get this right, is there any reason to use `TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` over `TEXTURE_2D` besides compatibility with contexts where GL_OES_EGL_image is not available for some reason? Are there even drivers out there that support OES_EGL_image_external without GL_OES_EGL_image, or otherwise have problems just using regular samplers? Regular samplers seem a lot more convenient than having to have special shader versions just for textures imported from EGL images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common use case for this is importing YUV video surfaces from camera/video decoders. For these you require the `TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` binding and matching samplers; the `TEXTURE_2D` path only handles the traditional RGBA data formats.

Comment: The spec could be more explicit about this, but I guess one could read it like that, so this answer is convincing enough for me.